# SmartGWT skinning

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, smartclient

Some `SmartGWT components` are composed by a lot of small images. This is the case of IButton for example that gets rendered using images.

I want to adapt the original `SmartGWT CSS` to fit my needs, that are basically *color changes*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is not quite accurate..

If you have staff with experience with image-based skinning and appropriate tools (eg Adobe Fireworks), start from whatever skin you like.

If you don't, and you need to change the colors but don't care about niceties like rounded corners in older IE (which are impossible without images), start from Simplicity, or start from the CSS3 rendering mode provided for the 3 most popular skins (from 3.1 on):

```
http://blog.isomorphic.com/css3-mode/
```

The latter approach (CSS3 mode) is more visually rich than Simplicity.

Comment: sweet jesus! This is new! and a nice feature. It's gona save my life for sure !

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the best way of skinning an SmartGWT application is starting from the `Simplicity` theme.

Isomorphic team suggest starting from this theme, as it uses less images that the others themes.

As far as I've read, everything should be done by hand (editing images, and CSS).